# setting up flutter on android studio error

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

error setting up flutter for android studio

I tried:
repeating the process
deleting android studio and restarting

error creating project

cannot create a project within the Flutter SDK Target directory
C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\flutter_app

is within the flutter SDK at C:\src\flutter

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to create a project within the flutter sdk folder. Try recreating it in a different location outside of this folder

Comment: Oh so the place where I would store the project should be different?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: awesome! I tried that and it works! thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Please do not create a project within the Flutter SDK directory. 
Please create your project in another directory.

Answer (score 0):

check the flutter sdk

file - > settings -> languages -> Flutter

[image]

Comment: I checked it but I'm confused what I am to do

the path says:

C:\src\flutter

Comment: @Edwin This shows you where the Flutter SDK is, and once you know that, you can avoid creating your projects therein, because as the message clearly states, Flutter doesn't allow that.